# how to create a c++ function which create new object every time user input new data?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

i'm new in c++ and i've been given an assignment where to create a program that can entry Employee Name, Work Hour, Overtime Duration.

There is a menu `Insert Employee`, `View Employee` where option view will display all list employee that already input before: Name, Work Hour, Overtime, Salary.

User limited to input max 5 Employee, so if user input 5 different employee, `View Employee` option will display all that 5.

I have already create a class `Employee` and i'm still confused how my `inputEmp` function to be able create new object every time user choose `Insert Employee` option?

Here's a brief of my code

```
class Employee {
    string name;
    int salaryTot, hour, overtime;

    public:
        Employee(){hour = 8;}
        void calcSalary(){
            int salary = hour * 20000;
            salaryTot = overtime * 30000 + salary;
        };
        void putName(string name){name = name};
        void putOvertime(int overtime){overtime = overtime};
        void getName(){return name;};
        void getHour(){return hour;};
        void getOvertime(){return overtime;};
        void getSalary(){return salaryTot;};

}

void inputEmp(){
    //<blabla_code> this line should create new object for this new user input
    cout<<string(12, '\n')<<"Input Employee's name [5-25] : ";
    cin>>//blabla.putName()
    cout<<"\nInput overtime's duration [0 - 4] : ";
    cin>>//blabla.putOvertime();
    //blabla.calcSalary
    cout<<"Success insert new employee!"<<endl;
}

void printALL(){
    cout<<"Name :"<<\\blabla.getName()
    cout<<"Work Hour :"<<\\blabla.getHour()
    cout<<"Overtime :"<<\\blabla.getOvertime()
    cout<<"Salary :"<<\\blabla.getSalary()
}

int Layout(){
    int choice = 0;

    while(choice !=3){
    do{
        cout<<string(12, '\n')<<"adeqecil COMPANY"<<endl;
        cout<<string(16, '=')<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Insert Employee"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.View Employee"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Input choice : "; cin>>choice;
    } while(choice <1 && choice >5);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: inputEmp();
        break;
        case 2: printAll();
        break;
        case 3: return 0; 
            break;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Emplayee>`.

Comment: I would say part of your difficulty is the signature of `void inputEmp(){` which does not really allow you return a new object (other than an ugly usage of global variables).

Comment: @drescherjm hi, thank you for answer. To create an object In the `void inputEmp(){` i have to change it to `int inputEmp()` and  add `Employee obj1` like it used to or there is another way?

Comment: Use `Employee inputEmp() {` or `void inputEmp(Employee & empCreated){`

Comment: Are you permitted to use a `std::vector`? that would also help this assignment.

Comment: @drescherjm okay, if i use `void inputEmp(Employee & empCreated){` what if i want to print the object data? because i don't know what the object name is. 
Sorry i'm still new in c++, thank you in advance

Comment: To print for your assignment you want an array or vector of Employee. You should have this vector as a local variable in main and pass by reference to your print function. The vector or array should have its employees initialized by your new inputEmp function in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is confusing : while(choice <1 && choice >5);

make a new object for every new employee and pass it into PrintALL function.

```
void printALL(emp_object_1){
cout<<"Name :"emp_object_1.getName();
cout<<"Work Hour :"emp_object_1.getHour();
cout<<"Overtime :"emp_object_1.getOvertime();
cout<<"Salary :"emp_object_1.getSalary(); }
```

Your code has so many errors. However, hope this helps.